# How can I check if a handler exists in backbone.radio?

Tags: backbone.js

I am switching my backbone.wreqr library in favor of backbone.radio
My code base uses extensibly the functions

```
const channel = wreqr.radio.channel("name")
channel.reqres.hasHandler("name")
channel.reqres.getHandler("name")
```

Though it seems there isn't a direct equivalent version of hasHandler and getHandler in radio.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just check for the type of the handler?

```
const channel = Radio.channel('name');
channel.on('mymethod', this.mymethod); // returns this.mymethod without executing it

const myhandler = channel.request('mymethod');

if (typeof myhandler !== 'undefined') myhandler();
```